# Modifying this function to read from a ';' separated file

Tags: c++, function, delimiter

Disclaimer this is for a homework question. Not asking for a full solution to the program I am writing, just asking for better understanding of what is happening. Thanks in advance.

The provided function is reading from a file that looks like this.

```
foo;bar
foo;bar
```

And  I would like to modify the function to read from a file that looks like

```
foo;bar;foobar
foo;bar;foobar
```

The provided function looks like

```
void EntryList::loadfile(const char filefoo[])
{
    ifstream        in;
    char            foo[MAX_CHAR];
    char            bar[MAX_CHAR];
    AddressEntry    anEntry;    

    in.open (filefoo);
    if(!in)
    {
        in.clear();
        cerr << endl << "Fail to open " << filefoo << " for input!" << endl << endl;
        exit(1);
    }   

    in.get(foo, MAX_CHAR, ';');
    while (!in.eof())
    {
        in.get();                       //remove field seperator ';'            
        in.get(bar, MAX_CHAR, '\n');
        in.ignore(100, '\n');               //remove record seperator '\n'  

        anEntry.setfoo(foo);
        anEntry.setbar(bar);    

        addEntry(anEntry);  

        in.get(foo, MAX_CHAR, ';');             //start the next record
    }
    in.close();
}
```

The function that I modified looks like

```
void EntryList::loadfile(const char fileName[])
{
    ifstream        in;
    char            foo[MAX_CHAR];
    char            bar[MAX_CHAR];
    char            foobar[MAX_CHAR];
    TaskList        theEntry;   

    in.open(fileName);
    if (!in) {
        in.clear();
        cerr << endl
        << "Failed to open "
        << fileName
        << " for input!" << endl << endl;
        exit(1);
    }   

    in.get(foo, MAX_CHAR, ';');
    while (!in.eof())
    {
        in.get(); // rm ;
        in.get(bar, MAX_CHAR, ';');
        in.get(foobar, MAX_CHAR, '\n'); // rm '\n'
        in.ignore(100, '\n');   

        theEntry.setfoo(foo);
        theEntry.setbar(bar);
        theEntry.setfoobar(foobar); 

        addEntry(theEntry); 

        in.get(foo, MAX_CHAR, ';'); 

    }   

    in.close(); 

}
```

I am in the middle of rewriting this program for at least the 4 time.
and I have modified the file how I (humanly) think I should
to this. I have had issues in the past, doing it this way. (still working on the other parts of the program so I cannot be too specific right now, but I know my results were unexpected ) So my question is does the function that I modified look correct for what I am trying to do? Am I off by one? I guess I am struggling with understanding how the original function is working. (step by step systematically.) hence my confusion about my modified function.

I can also provide any other functions you would like to take look at, my setters and getters. Also if you have any questions or feedback I would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: You do `in.get()` to skip the first `;`. What about the second one?

Comment: Yea, your probably on to some of what is confusing to me. The first instance `in.get(foo, MAX_CHAR, ';');`  in the provided function make no sense to me, why it is outside the while loop. It seems it is operating on some side effect that I am unfamiliar with, and really leaves me at a loss when, I think about modifying the file to have a second ';' as a delimiter. But I really can speak to your question, because the provided function is confusing to me.

Comment: Also ask for code review here: [stackexchange CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

Both the orginal and the modified functions are wrong: you **alway** need to check for successful input **after** trying to read something (I guess, if I eventually pass away my headstone will have that engraved...). Using `in.eof()` to control an input loop in general **does not** work!

If the line ends in a string with less than `MAX_CHAR` characters, the next line get ignored: you need to check if the input ends in a newline character and, if not, ignore the remaining character. If the last input ends with a newline character, you don't want to ignore characters. Also, if the line happens to end in a string with more than 100 characters, it also doesn't work. The magical constant for `std::istream::ignore()` to ignore as many characters as necessary is, inconveniently, spelled `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` and is declared in the header `<limits`>.

Basically, your loop should start with

```
while (in.getline(foo, MAX_CHAR, ';')
         .getline(bar, MAX_CHAR, ';')
         .get(foobar, MAX_CHAR, '\n')) {
    if (foobar[in.gcount() - 1] == '\n') {
        foobar[in.gcount() - 1] = '\0';
    }
    else {
        in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    // process the inputs
}
```

The code uses `std::istream::getline()` for the first two components to avoid the separate to be stored: it is sufficient if the separator is extracted and the input is stopped. For the last component `std::istream::get()` is used because it is necessary to verify if the last character stored was a newline. The last character stored is access using `std::istream::gcount()` which contains the number of characters stored by the last unformatted input function. Since the input succeeded and it would stop either when storing a newline or after storing `MAX_CHAR` characters, `in.gcount() - 1` is always a valid index. Note, however, that the code is not tested...

Comment: Thank you for your input. It is a little frustrating, that I have read a lot about why in.eof() is problematic, but it is being taught in class. The code you provided seems much more readable to me, and I can see what is happening procedurally. I have not yet finished the whole program, so I cannot report back yet. I will get back to you by the end of the weekend, and let you know (and others) how this worked out. Thank you again!

Comment: @user2404155: Please inform your teacher that some odd guy on the Internet tells him that he is teaching rubbish when advertising `std::istream::eof()` to control an input loop: we want future students to not suffer from teaching this particular bad approach! It should be fairly easy to verify that this particular odd guy has reasonable credentials when it comes to C++ IOStreams: a few Google searches should confirm that I'm reasonable knowledgable on IOStream, as should reading the first page of the IOStreams chapter of Nicolai Josuttis's "The C++ Sandard Library".